# NodeJS + Soket.IO чат и sql injection

Tags: sql, node.js

При отправке сообщения делается sql запрос

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO `'+config.db_prefix+'_chat`(`user_id`, `msg`) VALUES ("'+user_id+'", "'+msg.message+'")', function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        //тут рассылка клиентам в чате
});
```

И если в сообщении содержатся такие символы как  `/` и другими спец символами то процесс nodejs крашится и пишет ошибку sql синтаксиса как лучше реализовать "экранирование" без потери этих символов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не надо подставлять переменные непосредственно в текст запроса. Функции `query` можно передать массив подставляемых в запрос переменных. В самом тексте запроса переменные надо обозначить вопросительными знаками. Примерно так:

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO `'+config.db_prefix+'_chat`(`user_id`, `msg`) VALUES (?,?)',
                 [user_id,msg.message] , function (err, result) {
    ...
});
```